# Should React.PureComponent be used for components that are updated frequently?

Tags: performance, reactjs, flux

If a component needs to render several times a second because of a prop change, should this component extend React.PureComponent?

The component has no child components, however, it is itself deeply nested... so the props are travelling through several other components.

In general, what are some key things to consider when deciding if React.PureComponent should be used or not.  In which scenarios is it bad to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this sounds like a good case for PureComponent because your component is unnecessarily being re-rendered frequently with the same props.

A child component extended from React.Component will call `render` every time its parent calls `render`.  If instead the child component is extended from PureComponent it will only call `render` when the parent passes props that don't `shallowEqual` the previously passed props.

It's generally safe to use PureComponent as long as

- your component and its children don't rely on `context` updates
- your component doesn't have object or array props that are directly mutated by its parents (`shallowEqual` will not detect these changes)

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the prop has a different value several times a second....  If the render function is really simple, is it even worth the PureComponent to do that check so many times a second.  Also there are hundreds of these components on the page all changing with that frequency.

Comment: `shallowEqual` has very minimal performance costs, especially compared to `render` which has to create new elements and triggers a shadow DOM comparison.  If all your component instances are getting different props pretty much 100% of the time, then sure there's a minor performance hit from `PureComponent`.  But otherwise it's likely a net gain.